# how to check string contain any character other than number in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check String contain any character or special character other than number.I wrote following code for this

```
String expression = "[^a-zA-z]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(jTextFieldPurchaseOrder.getText().toString().trim());
```

It is working fine when i am taking value from jTextField and checking my condition. But giving error when checking String from DTO as below

```
list.get(0).getChalan_trans_id().toString().trim().matches("[^a-zA-z]");
```

Where list is arraylist of DTO.
I am not getting where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "But giving error" doesn't give us enough information. What happens? (And note that this is currently just seeing whether it has any non-A-Z letters in - it has nothing to do with numbers...)

Comment: _"I want to check String contain any character or special character other than number"_ . regex `\\D` is the best for that case

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[^a-zA-Z]` not `[^a-zA-z]`

Comment: So you want the string to have only numbers?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: giving error means it is not giving me correct result like string contain character then it is giving false result and if character is not present then giving true in checking condition.

Comment: Well please make that clearer, and give an example of it working incorrectly. But as I say, your pattern is checking for letters, not numbers...

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check if there is a non-digit character, you can use `.*\\D.*`:

```
if (list.get(0).getChalan_trans_id().toString().trim().matches(".*\\D.*")) {
    //non-digit found, handle it
}
```

or, maybe easier, do it the other way around:

```
if (list.get(0).getChalan_trans_id().toString().trim().matches("\\d*")) {
    //only digits found
}
```

Comment: @ALV: You are very welcome. I see in your profile that you haven't accepted an answer to any of your questions. It is important that you do this when you get an answer you are satisfied with, or you might get trouble getting future questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way than regular expressions. Regular expressions are powerful, but can be overkill for a simple task like this.

Something like this ought to work, and I would expect it to be quicker.

```
static boolean hasNonNumber(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```